# wxPython wx.CallAfter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, wxpython

I work with wxpython and threads in my project. I think that I didn't understand well how to use wx.CallAfter and when to us it. I read few thing but I still didn't got the point. Someone can explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, `wx.CallAfter` simply takes a callable and the parameters that should be passed to it, bundles that up into a custom event, and then posts that event to the application's pending event queue. When that event is dispatched the handler calls the given callable, passing the given parameters to it.

Originally `wx.CallAfter` was added in order to have an easy way to invoke code after the current and any other pending events have been processed. Since the event is always processed in the main UI thread, then it turns out that `wx.CallAfter` is also a convenient and safe way for a worker thread to cause some code to be run in the UI thread.